# Example for this criterion?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Here is a powerful criterion on sequences and series :

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R^+}^{\mathbb{N}}$ a decreasing sequence. If $A_n = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k$ converges then $a_n = o(\frac{1}{n})$.

I was looking for an interesting example which uses this criterion.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This just means the summands decay quickly enough.

Comment: Isn't this like a way to rephrase the test for $p$-series?

Comment: @stressedout test for $p$-series ?

Comment: Yeah. Read Chris's comment. In other words, what you have said probably can be linked to the test for $p$-series by considering $a_n$ equivalent to a rational function in $n$ or something.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly,  while the harmonic series $\sum\frac1n$ diverges (and, of course,  $\frac1n\not=\mathcal o (\frac1n)$), $\sum(\frac1n)^{1+\epsilon}$ converges for any $\epsilon \gt0$.

So the condition you have given is in a sense optimal...

Comment: Let $s>0$ an integer, then we define the finite set $E_s=\{n\in \mathbb{N} \ / \ a_n\ge \frac{1}{s} \}$ and denote by $K_s$ the size of $E_s$. Then apparently $K_s= o(s)$.